# What is EmguCV equivalent of fastAtan2() from OpenCV?

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am creating an app for detection of damage in fingerprints and for that I'm using some code made in C++. For orientations field algorithm there is this line I cannot find an equivalent in Emgu.CV.

```cs
finalEstimate = 0.5 * cv::fastAtan2(vx, vy);
```

This code is used for calculating an angle of one block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I feel a little dumb.

I found this: [Math.Atan2(Double, Double) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.atan2?view=netframework-4.7.2)